# Jolt transform json array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I need a help in Jolt transform.
I have array, that consist from many json objects. (https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ )

```json
[
  {
    "table_name": "table_vd",
    "scratch_name": "l1_sample_1_1",
    "scratch_order": 1
  },
  {
    "table_name": "table_vd",
    "scratch_name": "l1_sample_1_1",
    "scratch_order": 34
  },
  {
    "table_name": "table_vd",
    "scratch_name": "l1_sample_2",
    "scratch_order": 3
  }
]
```

What transformation of Jolt needs to be done to get the following result?

```json
{
  "table_name" : "table_vd",
  "data" : [ {
    "scratch_name" : "l1_sample_1_1",
    "scratch_order" : 1
  }, {
    "scratch_name" : "l1_sample_1_1",
    "scratch_order" : 34
  }, {
    "scratch_name" : "l1_sample_2",
    "scratch_order" : 3
  } ]
}
```

Now i have next Jolt construction:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "table_name": "table_name",
        "*": {
          "@0": "data[0].&1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But the *result* below is not correct:

```json
{
  "table_name" : [ "table_vd", "table_vd", "table_vd" ],
  "data" : [ {
    "scratch_name" : [ "l1_sample_1_1", "l1_sample_1_1", "l1_sample_2" ],
    "scratch_order" : [ 1, 34, 3 ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Pls post the code you have done so far and remove code from images to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started well by using conditional logic through seperating `"table_name"` and others(`"*"`). Rearrange "*"(*the rest*) as `"*": "data[&1].&"`, and then pick the first element of the values of `"table_name"` array through use of ***cardinality*** spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "table_name": "&",
        "*": "data[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "table_name": "ONE"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This helped me a lot in solving my task.